# Regular Expression with python need to select closest section

Tags: python, regex

Need some help with RegEx over python.
I have this text:

```
part101_add(
    name = "part101-1",
    dev2_serial = "dev_l622_01",
    serial_port = "/dev/tty-part101-1",
    yok_serial = "YT8388"
)
yok_tar_add("YT8388", None)
part2_add(
    name = "part2-1",
    serial_number = "SERIALNUMBER",
    serial_port = "/dev/tty-part2-1",
    yok_serial = "YT03044",
    yok_port_board = "N"
)
yok_tar_add("YT03044", None)
```

I need to select all part*_add and its content.
for example:

```
part101_add:

name = "part101-1",
dev2_serial = "dev_l622_01",
serial_port = "/dev/tty-part101-1",
yok_serial = "YT8388"

part2_add:
serial_number = "SERIALNUMBER",
serial_port = "/dev/tty-part2-1",
yok_serial = "YT03044",
yok_port_board = "N"
```

problem is that im unable to separate the results.
when using this pattern:

```
regex = r"(.*?_add)\([\s\S.]*\)"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would precise the pattern to only match at the start and end of the line, and use a lazy quantifier with `[\s\S]`:

```
r"(?m)^(part\d+_add)\([\s\S]*?\)$"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bBqamC/1)

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - an inline `re.MULTILINE` modifier version to make `^` match the line start and `$` to match the line end
- `^` - start of a line
- `(part\d+_add)` - Group 1 capturing `part`, 1+ digits, `_add`
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to
- `\)$` - a `)` at the end of the line.

Comment: That's great! even if your pattern selects also the yok_port_add - but i'm fine with that :)

Comment: Then, you may edit the `.*?` part - [`(?m)^(part\d+_add)\([\s\S]*?\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bBqamC/1) if you only want to select those lines starting with `part` + one or more digits.